# Rails filtering conditions on HABTM join table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope, has-and-belongs-to-many

```
 class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :appointments
   has_many :patients, through: :appointments
 end

 class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :physician
   belongs_to :patient
   scope :physicals, -> { where appointment_type: 'physical' }
 end

 class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :appointments
   has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
 end
```

How can I access a list of patients, for a physician, with physicals in a single query?  And the inverse (patients that have a different appointments of a different type)?  Can I then set this with something like `physician.patients_with_physicals = [patient]`?

Comment: Firstly,it is not `HABTM`.It is `has_many =>through`.

Answer (score 3):

The below will allow you to get the patients of any type in a single query:

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments

  def patients_with_appointment_of_type type
    self.patients.joins(:appointments)
      .where(:appointments => {:type => type})
  end
end
```

Where you wish to use `physician.patients_with_physicals = [patient]` how are you planning on filling in the other appointment data which I assume is required (time, etc)?

It's worth noting that `type` as a column is used by Rails to signify a model that uses single table inheritance (STI) and could cause you issues, so I would recommend using a different column name.

Comment: i'll change the field to something other than type

Comment: Did you have an answer to the question of how the remaining appointment data would be set (time, date, etc)? There are a number of ways you can set the type on the appointments when adding patients via a method (as in the question), but if other data is to be considered there is probably a better approach to take.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I access a list of patients, for a doctor, with physicals in a
>   single query?

Use [ActiveRecord Association Extensions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions):

```
#app/models/physician.rb
Class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :appointments
    has_many :patients, through: :appointments do
        def with(type)
           where(appointment_type: type)
        end
    end
end

#-> @doctor.patients.with("physicals")
#-> Patient #1 etc
```

Can you explain what you mean by:

> patients that have a different appointments of a different type)?